# Override 3 finger tap globally

Tags: macos

osx dictionary app has 3 finger tap on any word with look up window as result.

I want to add network module to dictionary.app (urbandictionary for example), according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96066/is-it-possible-to-add-other-networked-sources-to-the-apple-dictionary-program I can't.

So if dictionary module is not possible, I want to override 3 finger tap completely and show my own popup instead of dictionary.app. http://www.bettertouchtool.net/ does it. And I want to capture word under cursor, so I can look it up in my application.

How can I do it?